# How to find if function argument is a alphabet or not in python 3?

Tags: python, string, python-3.x

I am stuck while making a simple program in python 3. The code is below:

```
def check_guess(letter,guess):
    max = guess.isnumeric()
    #print(type(max))
    print(max)
    if(max == 'True'):
        print("Invalid")
        return False
    elif(guess > letter):
        print("High")
        return False
    elif(guess < letter):
        print("Low")
        return False
    else:
        print("Correct")
        return True

check_guess("H","2")
```

There is no error in the program but I am not getting the desired result. Whenever I try `check_guess("H","2")` it should return `Invalid` but it is showing `Low`. I want to print "Invalid" if `guess` parameter is not an alpha character in `check_guess()` function. How do I do that? Please help.

Comment: You're checking against a string `'True'`, not `True`.

Comment: `max` is a built-in function hence not a good name for a variable. Also, it is somewhat pointless to compare a Boolean with `True` since `if max == True:` is equivalent to `if max:`.

Comment: @Jim Fasarakis Hilliard. Thanks a lot. I got it.

Comment: @John Coleman. If I use `if max:` would result be `Invalid` as desired? Please elaborate. I am new to python and learning from online.

Comment: How on earth did you choose the variable name `max = guess.isnumeric()`? Strange choice. How about calling it `is_numeric`, better still don't assign it to a variable at all and just directly test `if(guess.isnumeric())`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## 1) `'True'` vs `True`

`'True'` is a string. `True` is the real Tautology boolean value. (See Jim's comment).

## 2) Don't redefine built-ins

First of all, don't use an intermediate variable, and don't name it a built-in function anyway. So, just do this:

```
if not letter.isnumeric():
    print("Invalid")
```

## 3) Check the right argument

You say you want to check if `letter` is valid but then you do `guess.isnumeric()` which checks `guess` instead.

Also, are you sure you want it to be invalid when the input is a number? I think you want `not letter.isnumeric()`... I think you also actually *do* want to check `guess`...

Comment: I didn't say to check `letter` argument. I have mentioned that I want to check  `guess` argument whether it is numeric or not. The code is about simple alphabet matching that's why I want to avoid numbers as argument of `guess_check()` function. I have just given the example of `check_guess("H", "2")` as of if you run the code I posted, it is gonna show you `Low`.

Comment: @Rajan You're testing `guess`, but `"H", "2"` has invalid `letter`... maybe switch your arguments?

Answer (score 0):

You should replace isnumeric with isalpha if you want to compare Two Alpha:

```
def check_guess(letter, guess):
    assert isinstance(letter, str)
    assert isinstance(guess, str)
    if not letter.isalpha() or not guess.isalpha():
        print("Invalid")
        return False
    if (guess > letter):
        print("High")
        return False
    elif (guess < letter):
        print("Low")
        return False
    else:
        print("Correct")
        return True

check_guess("H", "2")
```